# PHPUnit: Running Tests that Use a Specific Attribute

Tags: php, laravel, attributes, phpunit

I'm using the `RequiresFunction` attribute in a few of my tests. I want to pass arguments to `phpunit` that will run the tests with that attribute and the name of the required function (if possible).

Tests look something like this:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\RequiresFunction;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\Test;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MyCustomFunctionTest extends TestCase
{
    #[Test]
    #[RequiresFunction('some_function_name')]
    public function some_function_name_destroys_the_planet(): void
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple tests for different functions and you want more control, you can use the `@group` annotation in your test methods and then run PHPUnit with the `--group` option.

PHP:

```
#[Test]
#[Group('some_function_group')]
#[RequiresFunction('some_function_name')]
public function testSomeFunctionName(): void
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

Bash:

```
phpunit --group some_function_group
```

Comment: This will require making additional changes but is probably the cleanest solution, so I'm going to move forward with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run tests that require a specific function (like some_function_name), you can use PHPUnit's `--filter` option. However, the `--filter` option works with the names of the test methods or classes, not directly with attributes like RequiresFunction.

This command will run all tests whose names include `some_function_name`.

```
phpunit --filter '/some_function_name/'
```

Comment: This is something I currently use, but won't work for the scenario I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

in order to be able to test your file in php, you must observe two points:

1- Be sure to put the word Test at the beginning of the name of the file to be tested. (If there is no Test word, this can be told to the compiler manually, but it is better to put the Test word as below for easier testing)

```
TestMyCustomFunction
```

2- The name of the function to be tested must include the word test (this item can be introduced with the filter flag exactly as above, but it is better to follow it)

```
test_some_function_name_destroys_the_planet
```

Or

```
testSomeFunctionNameDestroysThePlanet
```

Or you can not include the word test, but use annotations like the following:

```
/**
 * @test
 */

 public function some_function_name_destroys_the_planet(): void
 {
     $this->assertTrue(true);
 }
```

If you use @test annotations, there is no need to write a test before the function word, and the compiler will recognize the function after @test

Comment: The `#[Test]` attribute takes the place of the prefix and annotation. Attributes are native to PHP so they perform better than prefixes and annotations.

Comment: Annotations are deprecated in PHPUnit 11 and will be removed in PHPUnit 12.

Comment: Attribute support was added in PHPUnit 10